# Celery configuration for retry backoff

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I want to have all asycnhronous tasks in my app retry on any exception and also want the retries to follow exponential backoff.

```
@celery_app.task(autoretry_for=(Exception,))
def some_task():
    ...
```

In my configuration I have

```
CELERY_TASK_ANNOTATIONS = {'*': {'max_retries': 5, 'retry_backoff': 5}}
```

The max_retries setting works and all tasks are now retried 5 times before failing. But all of them are retried after 180 seconds.
I want some way for all the tasks to follow `retry_backoff` without having to specify it for each of them so that I can change it anytime at one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to avoid changing this in multiple places is to have a global variable, say `global_retry_backoff=5` that you will use in your task annotations: `@celery_app.task(autoretry_for=(Exception,), retry_backoff=global_retry_backoff)` .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there is no way to set this in celery configuration.

Comment: I do not think so, but do not take my words for granted, I am still learning Celery...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like according to the [Celery documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#Task.retry_backoff) the property you want to set is `retry_backoff_max`.

> **Task.retry_backoff_max**

> A number. If retry_backoff is enabled, this option will set a maximum
> delay in seconds between task autoretries. By default, this option is
> set to 600, which is 10 minutes.

`retry_backoff` can be a number or a boolean and based on which it is the backoff will behave differently. For an exponential backoff it appears you want to set this true.

> **Task.retry_backoff**
>
> A boolean, or a number. If this option is set to
> True, autoretries will be delayed following the rules of exponential
> backoff. The first retry will have a delay of 1 second, the second
> retry will have a delay of 2 seconds, the third will delay 4 seconds,
> the fourth will delay 8 seconds, and so on. (However, this delay value
> is modified by retry_jitter, if it is enabled.) If this option is set
> to a number, it is used as a delay factor. For example, if this option
> is set to 3, the first retry will delay 3 seconds, the second will
> delay 6 seconds, the third will delay 12 seconds, the fourth will
> delay 24 seconds, and so on. By default, this option is set to False,
> and autoretries will not be delayed.

Comment: `retry_backoff` can be a boolean or a number, it even says so in the quoted docs.

Comment: Hah, you're right @guival, I will reword this. However, outside of the poorly worded response I believe the quoted documentation still provides the reason and the solution.